# Tor browser not opening

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Okay so earlier today I went to go use Tor so I can us stuff unblocked but when I went to open it its said that "This item 'firefox.exe' that this shortcut refers to has been changed or moved, so this shortcut will no longer work properly." if anyone knows a way around this please send help, im retarded :p